# Unwanted space appearing above linear layout

Tags: android

This is my LayoutActivity, and above the `LinearLayout` where are the "No, Name, Price and Change 24H." appear a big gap on my phone (Samsung S7), look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH4vB.png). On my Android Studio virtual machine, there isn't one, look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwjTu.png). What is causing this gap and how to fix it?

I include the LayoutActivity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#5078909c "
            android:text="Overview"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/portfolio_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Portfolio" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Settings" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:text="Refresh" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/CoinList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="385dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" >

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CoinList"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Background_for_buttons"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#803f51b5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Background_for_buttons"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#803f51b5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="NAME"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Background_for_buttons"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#803f51b5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="PRICE"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_test"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Background_for_buttons"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#803f51b5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CHANGE 24H."
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try changing your root to LinearLayout and apply weighSum, Orientation...

Comment: android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" try removing this and make it bottom of element above

Comment: @D.'s These things don't seem to work

Comment: add `android:layout_below` to your item that gets displaced

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` has a fixed height and is aligned with parent's bottom. Your `LinearLayout` with headers is put on top of the `ListView`. So based on vertical resolution of the screen there may or may not be a gap between the `LinearLayout` and the top of the screen. More specifically, if the screen is taller than 30+385 dp you'll see a gap.

What you probably want to do is align the headers layout with the top of the parent, align the list to the bottom of the headers and make lists's height "match_parent"

Edit: didn't notice the refresh button. You may also need to put

```
android:layout_above="@+id/refresh_button"
```

on the `ListView`